# Running a custom function from appscript onto sheets returns an error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, exception, google-sheets-formula, custom-function

***TLDR: I want to use a custom function (`getFirstFruit`) in a spreadsheet (Spreadsheet B) from an imported library (Script Project A), but it is returning an error stating that I do not have permission***

---

**Google Spreadsheet A**

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Apples | Bananas | Carrots |
| 2 | Dumplings | Eggplant | Figs |

- Named Range (A1:C2) = 'Range_Fruits'
- Spreadsheet ID = 'abcde'

**Google Apps Script Project A - Linked to Spreadsheet A**

*Code.gs*

```
function getFruits() {
  return SpreadsheetApp
    .openById('abcde')
    .getRangeByName('Range_Fruits')
    .getValues()
    .reduce((a,b) => a.concat(b), []);
}
```

*appscript.json*

```
{
  "timeZone": "Australia/Sydney",
  "dependencies": {},
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "oauthScopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"]
}
```

- console.log correctly returns ['Apples','Bananas','Carrots','Dumplings','Eggplant','Figs']
- Script A is deployed as a library.

---

**Google Apps Script Project B - Linked to Spreadsheet B**

- Script A is added as a library named 'LibraryScriptA'

*Code.gs*

```
function getFirstFruit() {
  return LibraryScriptA.getFruits()[0];
}
```

- console.log correctly return 'Apples'

*appscript.json*

```
{
  "timeZone": "Australia/Sydney",
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "dependencies": {
    "libraries": [
      {
        "userSymbol": "LibraryScriptA",
        "version": "0",
        "libraryId": "AtpircSyrarbiL-lobmySresu_0-noisrev",
        "developmentMode": true
      }
    ]
  },
  "oauthScopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"]
}
```

**Google Spreadsheet B**

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | =getFirstFruit() |  |  |
| 2 |  |  |  |

- Value in A1 returns **"#ERROR!**

  > Exception: You do not have permission to call SpreadsheetApp.openById. Required permissions: `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets`

I have tried:

- When the popup to authorize script comes up, I allow it for both script project files
- I have manually added the oauthScopes for spreadsheets
- console.log every step to find the point where it breaks down. It appears that the scripts work correctly as shown above, but its when the function is called in the actual spreadsheet where it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

This runs for me:

```
function getFruits() {
  let x = SpreadsheetApp
    .openById("testsourceid")
    .getRangeByName('Range_Fruits')
    .getValues()
    .reduce((a,b) => {
      a = a.concat(b);
      return a;
    }, []);
    //Logger.log(x);
    return x;
}
```

returns: `[Apples, Bananas, Carrots, Dumplings, Eggplant, Figs]`

But perhaps I misunderstand how you are running it.

This returns the same thing:

```
function getFruits() {
  let x = SpreadsheetApp
    .openById(gobj.globals.testsourceid)
    .getRangeByName('Range_Fruits')
    .getValues().flat();
    Logger.log(x);
    return x;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but the issue isn't so much the code itself. That's probably my fault for not making that clear. But the issue is that when I try to call that function on a spreadsheet, it returns as an error.

Comment: And just to make it super clear, if I call the function on the spreadsheet that is linked to the script file, it works fine. But if I call the function on non-linked spreadsheet (but connected via the script file being a library), it does not work and returns an error